# ggplot2 stat_function line cuts off too early before asymptote

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I am working on a graph in ggplot2, and I am using stat_function to define a line.  The data I am working with has limits, and I want the line to continue through as much of the limits as possible.  Here is an example of what I am working on.

```
fun1<-function(x,y){y=2000000/x}

x<-seq(0,100,1)
y<-seq(0,800000,8000)
df<-data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
    stat_function(fun=fun1)+
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,800000))+
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,80))
```

The line on the left cuts off around x = 3, but I would like it to stop right before it gets to x = 0.

**Update**

I found the solution to my problem.  I created a curve and added it to the plot using geom_line.

```
x<-seq(0,100,1)
y<-seq(0,800000,8000)
df<-data.frame(x,y)

fun1<-function(x,y){y=2000000/x}
mycurve1 <- as.data.frame(curve(from=2.5, to=100, fun1))


ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
     geom_point()+
     scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,800000),expand=c(0,0))+
     scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,100),expand=c(0,0))+
     geom_line(data=mycurve1,aes(x=x,y=y))
```

Answer (score 0):

As `x` is only in whole numbers, the y value for `x = 2` falls outside the limits you have set for the y-scale. As a result, the line is cut off at `x = 3`. Just change the limits of the y-scale and you aredone. An example:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
    stat_function(fun=fun1)+
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,4000000))+
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,80))
```

Comment: I have other data involved where I can't extend the limits without distorting it.